# Identifying that a resolution is virtual on a X11 screen by it's API (or extensions)

Tags: c, linux, x11

I'm working in a embarked application on linux that can be used with different PC hardware (displays specifically)

This application should set the environment for the highest allowed resolution (get by 
the function XRRSizes from libXrandr).

The problem is: With some hardware, trying to set for the highest option creates a virtual desktop i.e. a desktop where the real resolution is smaller and you have to scroll w/ the mouse in the edges of the screen to access all of it.

Is there a way to detect within the Xlib (or one of it's siblings) that I am working with a  virtual resolution (In other words, the re-size didn't go as expected) ?

Hints for a work around for this situation would also be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to mention that I used XRRSetScreenConfigAndRate to change the display resolution

Comment: Just to clarify: do you actually want to identify that, or just find out what the largest non-virtual screen size is? Also, do you want to handle multi-monitor setups (where one monitor doesn't handle sizes the second one does)? And just as a side note: the highest screen size sometimes *does not* actually work.

Comment: OK, clarifying... I want to find out what the largest non-virtual screen size is supported. Also in case of it not working, identify this situation so I can handle it, and yes, I must handle two different monitors, one where the application is running plus another

Comment: Would you be able to use the X11 api to find out if the created window contains a scrollable bar?  If it does, then can't you just start shifting through smaller resolutions one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/randrproto/tree/randrproto.txt

You need to learn the difference between "screen", "output" and "crtc". You need to check the modes available for each of the outputs you want to use, and then properly set the modes you want on the CRTCs, associate the CRTCs with the outputs, and then make the screen size fit the values you set on each output.

Take a look at the xrandr source code for examples: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c

Comment: Saying ”You need to learn the difference between "screen", "output" and "crtc".“ is not helpful, when the linked document does not define the term "crtc".